# Pandas iloc and loc error of index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pick the particular row from the Pandas Matrix and get the column header title where row value is 1. Eg 
For Row GAO(in CSV) it has 1 under 4 headers "press release","Statements","Policy Brief","White Papers" (last 2 header is not visible to you.). So I want to save those header titles under a List variable.

[image].This is the code I am using

```
def csvTomatrix():

    matrixData = pd.read_csv("contentParameter.csv",index_col=[0])
    print(type(matrixData))
    print (matrixData.loc["CRS"])
```

This is the [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcSgv.png).

Note: I am using python3.6.

Comment: You've not told `pandas` to treat the first column as the index which is why you get this error. Try `matrixData = pd.read_csv("contentParameter.csv", index_col=[0])`. By default it auto generates an index of type `RangeIndex`

Comment: That worked like a charm. Just a question what is this index_col=[0]. Since we haven't defined it anywhere. Is it pre defined ?

Comment: You can pass as a param value the index position or the name of the column to treat as the index, see my answer below. Also don't post links to images, we prefer your code in text form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not told `pandas` that the first column is the index, try

```
matrixData = pd.read_csv("contentParameter.csv", index_col=[0])
```

or

```
matrixData = pd.read_csv("contentParameter.csv", index_col='Source\Content')
```

by default it auto generates one for you.

`loc` uses [`label`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) based indexing, and `iloc` uses [positional](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) based indexing.

As the label `'CRS'` didn't exist then `matrixData.loc["CRS"]` raised a `KeyError`, if you did `matrixData.iloc[0]` then this would have returned the first row

To answer your last question you can generate a boolean mask of the values that meet the criteria to mask against the columns. So assuming that `'Source/Content'` is now the index:

```
df.loc['GAO'] == 1.0
```

will generate a boolean mask, we can use this to mask against the columns:

```
df.columns[df.loc['GAO'] == 1.0]
```

Comment: If suppose I want header of that column where the value is 1. How do we get that?

Comment: @Hayat sorry I don't understand your question, what are you after? Can you edit your question

Comment: Referring to csv file I want to get header title for that column where the value is 1.
Eg 
For GAO (in CSV) value of" press release" and "statement" is 1 .So I can save thses 2 title in a variable.

Comment: Refer to my last comment, edit your question with a complete explanation

Comment: I have edited. The sorry Incomplete comment was posted.In case If I have not made anything clear please tell me.

Comment: When I say edit your question I mean in your actual question above, posting comments here is counter-productive. Anyway to get what you want you need `df.columns[df.loc['GAO'] == 1.0]]`

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new here. I am learning organized edits. I did it now.

Comment: See updated answer, you should really post some raw text of your data along with your code.

Comment: I worked. thanks. Next time I keep things in mind. Proper edits and organised questions. Cheers.